# Shut down PC at a determined time

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, power, scheduled-tasks

I have a software (calibre ebook manager) that fetches news at 6 am. I want to do the following :

1. Wake computer at 5:50 if not already on.(easily done in bios)
2. A scheduler opens calibre at 5:55 (done)
3. Calibre fetches the news as it starts up.

The above steps were easy to accomplish, but there are some problems. I want to shutdown the pc IF AND ONLY IF it was started at 5:50 automatically. If , for some reason, the pc was already on, I DO NOT WANT to shut it down.

How should that be done ?

Comment: Hack: when the PC is booted up, write a value via a script, such as the on time. Save this value to a file on your PC. Then, at shutdown time, check the value of this file and act accordingly.

Comment: Cool idea, wrote a script for it, without the need to save it.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) Script that does it. Make sure you run this script on boot. (Add a shortcut in startup folder)

```
;
; AutoHotkey Version: 1.x
; Language:       English
; Platform:       Win9x/NT
; Author:         AEonAX
;
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
if (A_Hour=5 and A_Min>55 and A_Min<59) ;Check if script starting time between 05:55 and 05:59 (24Hr clock)
{
Sleep,1000*60*5     ;Waits 5 Minutes
msgbox,4,,Will Shutdown in 60 seconds. Do you want to Stop the Shutdown.,60 ;Shows a msgbox for 60 seconds, If no response then shutsdown
ifmsgbox,Yes
    MsgBox Shutdown Cancelled
else
    Shutdown,1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the condition is to reset only if computer was booted automatically at 5:50 i guess one way would be to **rely on boot time**. You might adjust the minute timer to detect if when BIOS start computer at 5:50 what boot time is seen by system. But this a detail.

For the shutdown and detecting a boot time you can use following powershell script:

```
# GETTING BOOT TIME
$last_boot_date_time = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}

# SELECTING HOUR:MINUTES:SECONDS PART OF THE DATE
$last_boot_time_only = $last_boot_date_time | foreach { ([String]$_).split(" ")[1] }

# CHECKING IF BOOT TIME EQUALS 05:50
# IF SO - INITIATE SHUTDOWN
if ( $last_boot_time_only.split(":")[0] -eq "05" -and $last_boot_time_only.split(":")[1] -eq "50")
{ 
    Write-host "Shutting down in 10 seconds."; 
    shutdown -s -f -t 10
}
```

This is assuming you are using Windows with powershell version 1 or 2. If you have higher version of powershell, you might want to replace the command that gets the boot time with `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select lastbootuptime`

Comment: wont the boot time vary a bit with every boot ?

Comment: It might vary a bit, but unless you make some big change how much could it vary really? Couple of seconds at maximum. I think that is minor issue that could be fixed with additional if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below batch script, it rely's on the the system uptime. Run this when you think it is appropriate, with the Scheduler

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr Boot ^| findstr System') do (
  set output=%%a
  set /a hrs=!output:~1,1!
  set mins=!output:~3,2!
 ::echo !output!
 ::echo !hrs! 
 ::echo !mins!
if !hrs! == 5 (
    if !mins! == 50 (
        shutdown -s -f -t 100
    )
) 

)
```

Well that is the idea, tweak as required

**Explanation.**

1. Extract the time that the computer was switched on,

> systeminfo ^| findstr Boot ^| findstr System

systeminfo has a lot of information in there, So we are filtering only the parameter that we need we are looking for.
eg,

> C:\Users>systeminfo | findstr Boot |findstr System
>
> System BootTime:          12/4/2014, 7:20:37 AM

2. Select the time field only that is separated by the comma

> for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr Boot ^| findstr System') do (
>         set output=%%a

and in that entire string only select the 1st character ( 1 space),  the 3rd and 4th character (2 space)

> set /a hrs=!output:~1,1!
>   set mins=!output:~3,2!

To give only the hr and the minute

3. IF function to shutdown if the time is a match.

> if !hrs! == 5 (
>
> ```
>   if !mins! == 50 (
>
>       shutdown -s -f -t 100
> ```

PS: The bellow is the comment to see, if there is any mistake in the code,

> ::echo !output!
>
> ::echo !hrs!
>
> ::echo !mins!

Comment: If you check only one character at `~38,1` - wont it by a chance trigger at 15:50 as well? Just a thought :)

Comment: I think it would still work, because if the other character comes in place, it would move the enter positioning, and it will not match the if function to initiate shutdown.

Comment: i am not so much into cmd. could you explain what your script is doing? Maybe add comments ?

Comment: i have modified it with explanations, hope this helps. Copy and save it in a '.bat' file. ;)

Comment: @Charm_quark if I see this correctly, your script depends on the date as well in `System BootTime: 12/4/2014, 7:20:37 AM`. `~38,1` will work when date has particular length, for example `12/4/2014` but I think the length in your command may vary. It can be `1/4/2014` (shorter) and it can be `12/12/2014` (longer) - I think it might cause your script to fail.

Comment: @Charm_quark i think you need nested `for` with delims set to `,`

Comment: yup, i see my error, I modified it again ( I used the same logic, that if the time changes to two places it will not be equal). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try  nncron  for Windows
http://www.nncron.ru/help/help.htm
English version

Comment: Please expand your answer and explain how to use the software for the specific problem mentioned in the question.